# Transferring contacts from iCloud to Android

Tags: icloud, data-transfer, android

I have a Samsung Android phone and need to transfer my iCloud contacts to that phone. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You may want to ask this over at the [Android Stack Exchange site](http://android.stackexchange.com/), if you don't get a satisfactory answer here.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the app [SmoothSync for Cloud Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.carddav.icloud) to accomplish that. The app will just add another standard sync account in Android under System settings > Accounts & sync where you can login with your Apple ID:

[image]

After you've setup the new account all your iCloud contacts will be synced down to the Android device and appear in the People app. Moreover, it's a full two-way sync so you can edit your iCloud contacts from your Android phone and the changes will get pushed to iCloud and your iDevices immediately.

Comment: I’m not sure, if this is save. Yes, iCloud contacts are just CardDAV, but I’m unsure, if even can login to iCloud with a non-Apple device

Comment: @SebastianSemmler no problems over here for a long time. Apple doesn't restrict iCloud login to Apple devices

Answer (score 2):

Simple and no need for additional apps:

1. [Export of your iCloud contacts to your computer](http://transfer-iphone-contacts.blogspot.com/2013/01/export-icloud-contacts.html) in vCard form.
2. Connect your Android to your computer and once it appears as a device, go to your Android "Storage"
3. Drag and drop the vCard file containing all your iCloud contacts to your Android Storage
4. On your Android, go to your Contacts app, tap the "Menu" and tap on "Import/Export > Import from USB storage > Import all vCard files". Your iCloud contacts are imported to your Android

Comment: Which folder to place the vcard file so the contact app can see it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Google Drive](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/google-drive-free-online-storage/id507874739?mt=8&at=1001lwpF) app to perform a backup of your iOS device. Your contacts will be added to Google Contacts when you perform the backup.

[image]